# code igniter - how to submit an ajax javascript object to the database with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, post

I have a javascript array of data that I want to submit to my codeigniter database:

```
[
  {
    "name": "title",
    "value": "myTitle"
  },
  {
    "name": "content",
    "value": "myContent."
  }
]
```

I want to submit this data to codeigniter, and have it update the database. ***Note that this is not data coming from a form, so I can't just use the typical code igniter form_open() / serialize() method***. I am using an ajax post and dynamically building the data:

```
    var submissionData = [];
    instanceFields.each(function(index){
            var $thisField = $(this);
            var thisData = {};
            thisData.name =$thisField.attr('data-name');
            thisData.value = $thisField.text();
            submissionData.push(thisData);
    });

    var submissionString = {arr: JSON.stringify(submissionData)};
    var submissionURL = baseURL + 'instances/edit';
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: submissionURL,
    data: submissionString,
    success: function(data){
        console.log("success:",data);},
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        console.error("error:",errMsg);
    }
```

Normally, for data posted from a form, I could access it like this in code igniter:

```
$this->input->post('title')
```

But if I echo that out here, I get an empty string.

I would then insert the data like this:

```
$data = array(

            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'content' => $this->input->post('content'),

        );

        return $this->db->insert('extra_instances', $data);
```

If I decode the JSON and do a var dump, it looks like this:

```
success: array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#19 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "title"
    ["value"]=>
    string(21) "myTitle"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#20 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "content"
    ["value"]=>
    string(238) "myContent"
  }
}
```

How can I modify this to insert into the database?

Comment: why all of that looping/push stuff? Why not just `.serialize()` on the form object?

Comment: There is no form. I am taking html fields with the "contenteditable" attribute and getting their values dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you mean that you want to send directly the object to insert into the database so

**Javascript**: You send the array into the $_POST key 'insertData'

```
var submissionData = [];
instanceFields.each(function(index){
        var $thisField = $(this);
        var thisData = {};
        thisData.name =$thisField.attr('data-name');
        thisData.value = $thisField.text();
        submissionData.push(thisData);
});


var submissionURL = baseURL + 'instances/edit';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: submissionURL,
    data: {
        insertData : submissionData
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log("success:",data);
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        console.error("error:",errMsg);
    }
});
```

**PHP Controller**: Receive the post, and you can insert an array directly to do both inserts.

```
$data = $this->input->post('insertData');
return $this->db->insert('extra_instances', $data);
```

Comment: great answer @jsertx upvote 5years never late chief